# Robocopy pattern matching

Tags: powershell-2.0, robocopy

I'm trying to filter files from one directory to another using robocopy for powershell.  However, I need to filter them mathcing a word in the name.  For example, many of the files contain debug, "SomeFileName_Debug.bat".  Is there a way to match only those files?  Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you could use asterisk sign for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"*debug*"` to match any name with debug inside it.